# json_decode outputs nothing (trying to get json_encode'd data from external php file)

Tags: php, jquery, json

In `_check_existing_transaction_partners.php`

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ajax_existing_company_error);
echo '</pre>';
```

(*using `json_encode` I comment this. Now show only as example*)

outputs this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

and `echo json_encode($ajax_existing_company_error);`

outputs this `["1","2"]`

Jquery code to send data to external file and receive back

```
var checkbox_to_update = $("#checkbox_to_update").val();
$.post("_check_existing_transaction_partners.php", { 'checkbox_to_update': checkbox_to_update }, function(data, success) {
alert(data);
}, "json");
```

With `alert(data);` get popup with `1,2`. So far all OK.

---

Trying instead of popup get some other format (to process latter)

Tried `$('#json_load').val(data);` and `<div id="json_load"></div>`. See nothing

Then tried `$myArray = json_decode($ajax_existing_company_error);` and `<?php print_r($myArray); ?>` Also see nothing.

Please advice how to get `$myArray = json_decode($ajax_existing_company_error);` or `$('#json_load').val(data);`

**Update**

Regarding `json_decode` In `_check_existing_transaction_partners.php` is `echo json_encode($ajax_existing_company_error);`

Then `jquery`

```
var checkbox_to_update = $("#checkbox_to_update").val();
$.post("_check_existing_transaction_partners.php", { 'checkbox_to_update': checkbox_to_update }, function(data, success) {
<?php print_r(json_decode($ajax_existing_company_error)); ?>
}, "json");
```

With View source see nothing related with `json_decode`

Then placed `<?php print_r(json_decode($ajax_existing_company_error)); ?>` just before closing `</body>`. Also see nothing

Comment: `$('#json_load').val(data);` should be `$('#json_load').html(data);`

Comment: Works. Yes, possibly I have asked something similar. I tried. Did not work. Searched for some time. Did not find solution. So asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `div`, you don't use `val()`: you use `html()` or `text()`

```
$('#json_load').val(data);
```

should be

```
$('#json_load').html(data);  // or
//$('#json_load').text(data);
```

Comment: Yes, works. But how to get `json_decode`? Tried `<?php print_r(json_decode($ajax_existing_company_error)); ?>` but see no array

Comment: Post all your PHP code related to this question, its hard to guess with only 1 line of code without knowing the variable declaration itself

Comment: Posted in question after Update. `$ajax_existing_company_error` is variable defined in external php file. I use `echo json_encode($ajax_existing_company_error);` In `$ajax_existing_company_error` array is included. Array like ``[0] => 1 [1] => 2`` Actually do not want you to waste time. If at once know problem, please write. If it takes time, I suppose I will get solution myself latter.